# Firebase query in query

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make multiple queries to my Firebase database, but it seems I am doing something wrong, and I just can't seem to understand what.

My code is this:

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Tbl1");

    Query tbl1Query = ref.orderByChild("type");

    tbl1Query .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Tbl1Item item = singleSnapshot.getValue(Tbl1Item .class);
                    tbl1List.add(item);
                }
                DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Tbl2");
                Query tbl2Query = ref.orderByChild("status");
                tbl2Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                tbl2Item item = singleSnapshot.getValue(tbl2Item.class);
                                tbl2List.add(item);
                            }
                            DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Tbl3");
                            Query tbl3Query = ref.orderByChild("status");
                            tbl3Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            tbl3item item = singleSnapshot.getValue(tbl3item.class);
                                            tbl3List.add(item);
                                        }
                                        SortTableData();
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is that the app crashes though I get no error in console.

What I am trying to obtain, is create 3 lists of objects with data from table1, table2 and table3 and then call a method that will process that data.

If I remove the 2nd and 3rd queries, everything works fine, but I don't have all the needed data... so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can't the listener on tbl2 be added outside!!!!

Comment: @SaiNageswar S not sure I understand what you mean